# Match any word which contains a particular string of characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I apologise in advance for the poor title of this post.

I'm trying to match any word which contains a certain string of characters i.e. if I wanted to match any words which contained the string 'press' then I would want the following returned from my search,

- press
- expression
- depression
- pressure

So far I have this `/press\w+/` which matches the word and any following charachers but I don't know how to get the preceding characters.

Many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
 /\w*press\w*/
```

`*` is "zero or more", where as `+` is "one or more". Your original regex wouldn't match just `"press"`.

#### See also

- [regular-expressions.info/Repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)

Answer (score 3):

Since your certain string of characters may not be known at compilation time, here is a function that does the work on any string:

```
function findMatchingWords(t, s) {
    var re = new RegExp("\\w*"+s+"\\w*", "g");
    return t.match(re);
}

findMatchingWords("a pressed expression produces some depression of pressure.", "press");
// -> ['pressed','expression','depression','pressure']
```

Comment: That's very nice. For a robust generic solution you may want to escape `s`, it may contain regex control characters.

Comment: True. Sadly, Javascript doesn't provide such a regexp-escaping function.